# In what war was the Maximov twins' home destroyed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the Age of Ultron, the Maximov twins describe hating Tony Stark because a missile with Stark's name on it landed in their apartment when they were children.

**In what war was that missile shot into the Maximov home?**

I assume this was an American missile shot into a Sokovian home.

Comment: I got the impression that it was a Sokovian civil war. Just because the missile was American-made doesn't mean it was used by Americans.

Comment: "Just because the missile was American-made doesn't mean it was used by Americans. " Exactly. Remember that Stane was double-dealing arms to terrorists.

Comment: Iron man 1 starts with the enemy using stark weapons on American troops and Stark himself. Stark missiles were everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Since Sokovia is a fictional country and no named war/conflict is mentioned, there is no absolutely accurate way to discern which war they are referring to.

However, we can do a little bit of informed speculating.

First up let's look at the time frame.

The twins explain that they were 11 when their parents were killed.

HYDRA acquires Loki's scepter sometime shortly before *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (detailed in *The Age Of Ultron Preview: The Scepter'd Isle*). Immediately following this, the twins are recruited by HYDRA.

Obviously, the twins are no longer children in 2014. Visually speking, roughly 10 or so years having passed makes sense.

We know that Sokovia is somewhere in Eastern Europe (stated in both *Age of Ultron*, and *Agents of SHIELD*), and the signage we see in the area is written in Cyrillic.

The *Age of Ultron* preview comic mentions a bit about what the protestors are rallying against: namely lack of protection by the government and oppression.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The general location, the vague description of the conflict, and the general timeframe leads me to believe that the war in Sokovia is meant to reflect [The 2004 Unrest in Kosovo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_2004_unrest_in_Kosovo).**

Alternatively, there were some slightly earlier conflicts which may also match depending on how you interpret the ages of the twins:

- [The Kosovo War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovo_War)
- [The Albanian Rebellion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_Rebellion_of_1997)
- [The Bosnian War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnian_War)

Comment: So, does that mean that the in-universe war where their parents were killed is not explicitly mentioned in any official sources?

Comment: @Ellesedil So far, no. Maybe in a commentary once the dvd/bluray is released.

Comment: Both marvel and dc tend to make to countries as needed with little back story. Honestly we know all that is needed to know about the twins so I wouldn't expect a single peep more

Comment: Makes sense, swap 's' and 'k' and you have Sokovo instead of Kosovo.